# ASP.NET C# Javascript div Centering

Tags: javascript, css, overlay, center

I want to, when the user clicks a button on my website, to make a `DIV` appear in the center of the browser above all other content on the website. I have created the `DIV` and even have the visible/hidden thingy figured out. The overlaying and the centering parts are what I am unable to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're talking about a shadowbox/modal window.  Microsoft provides an example of this in their [AJAX control toolkit](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) if you want to stay strictly C#.  This can also be done easily with third party API's, using jQuery, such as [ShadowBox.js](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/) or [DOM Window](http://swip.codylindley.com/DOMWindowDemo.html)

The works done for you.  You just need to plug it in.